# How do two-leaded color changing LEDs work?

Tags: led, identification

I have a few 3mm color-changing LEDs which I harvested from a toy. They fade in between all different colors, and then after a little while, they blink crazily between all the colors. After a few moments, the cycle repeats.

What is interesting about them (and what I wasn't expecting) is that they only have two leads, like a normal hobbyist LED.

I understand that, like an RGB LED, they have multiple elements (probably not the right word) inside. But how do they achieve the color changing and cycling?

Here is a picture of the LED in question:

[image]

Notice the little bit of black material inside the LED. Could this possibly be a tiny chip?

Comment: That's a 5mm led, not 3mm ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I expect they contain a tiny chip (you can see the little black thing inside) which sequences the patterns. It's either a microcontroller or a special purpose IC.

Most likely something like [one of these](http://www.bowin-ic.com.hk/icdatabook.html#10):

They're available in bare die form and connected to the LEDs inside by ultrasonically welded little wires.

[image: LED Flasher chip inside LED]

Comment: Neat, thanks! Unfortunately, mine are diffused so I can't see through to the die.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a chip (probably a simple microcontrolleer) inside the LED.

Comment: Interesting. Does that increase production costs dramatically?

Comment: @SimpleCoder - Well, what's the difference in purchase price?

Comment: Not sure - I scavenged them